# Java : Two Filtering Questions

Tags: java, filter

The following Filter sample I found works great.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
public class FilterExample  extends JFrame 
{
   private JTable table;
   private TableModel model;

   public FilterExample () 
   {
      setTitle("FilterTable Test");
      Object rows[][] = {{"Adithya", "Content Developer", 25000}, {"Jai", "SME", 30000},  {"Chaitanya", "Java Engineer", 45000}, {"Ramesh", "Scala Developer", 40000}, {"Ravi", "SAP  Consultant", 70000}};
      Object columns[] = {"Name", "Designation", "Salary"};

      model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
         public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            Class returnValue;
            if((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
               returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            } else {
               returnValue = Object.class;
            }
            return returnValue;
         }
      };

      table = new JTable(model);

      final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
      table.setRowSorter(sorter);

      add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      JLabel label = new JLabel("Filter");
      panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);

      final JTextField filterText = new JTextField("");
      panel.add(filterText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      JButton button = new JButton("Filter");
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = filterText.getText();

            if(text.length() == 0) {
               sorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
               try {
                  sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
               } catch(PatternSyntaxException pse) {
                     System.out.println("Bad regex pattern");
               }
             }
         }
      });

      add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      setSize(400, 300);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);

   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      new FilterExample ();
   }
}
```

When executed it generates the following :

[image]

If "Ja" is entered it produces this :

[image]

***Question 1 :*** 
How can I find within an object that the Filter is "Ja"?
Even when running within an IDE and a breakpoint, I was unable to located where this info is stored.

When attempting to find a ("Salary > 10000") , it wouldn't find any data.

[image]

***Question 1 :*** 
How can I Filter on a specific field and how to tell if the Filter on the table is on a single field or on all fields like in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

To answer **Question 1**: If you look at the code you provided you will see that when you press the `Filter` button the input will be stored in a `String` called `text`.

If you add a `system.out.println(text);` after text has been set you will see your input.

```
... // more code
  JButton button = new JButton("Filter");
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = filterText.getText(); // The variable your input is stored to
        System.out.println(text);
... // More code
```

To answer **Question 2**: When you try to filter `salary > 10000`, you are filtering a exactly that. You look for `"salary > 10000"` and not for a `salary` that is `>` than `10000`. To do so, you have to alter your code where the filter is applied.

**Edit:** To retrieve the text information out of the class you could initialize `FilterExample` in your main method alike: `FilterExample filter = new FilterExample();`. This allows us to call methods from the class where we can init a method to return a private variable from the class (which we will set to the input). Then whenever the button is pressed the string will be stored in this private variable, which we can access with, example: `String text = filter.getText();`. Since your filter only updates once the button is pressed you have to figure out when to access the `getText()` though, and if you do not initialize it, it will remain `null`.

Comment: For Question 1, I am looking to extract that value from the JTable object as I would need it at a later time. Also, if the JTable is passed to another routine, that routine may need to find that value.

Comment: @UnhandledException you mean that you want to retrieve the variable in your main function?

Comment: I guess a better question is where within the JTable is the filter information stored and how to retrieve it from the JTable object itself.

Comment: @UnhandledException, at the same location I am printing `text` you could instead create a private class variable such as `private String classText` and then a method called `getText()` which will return `classText`. But then you also need to initialize FilterExample() which is maybe not what you are aiming for?

Comment: No, the main objective is to locate where within the JTable, Sorter or what ever class the information is actually stored.

Comment: @UnhandledException, I would recommend reading the JavaDocs for this certain scenario. What you are doing is a actionlistener, which will WHEN the button is pressed execute the code followed. If you wonder where the input is stored you can look at where we from we are retrieving the information. `filterText.getText()` gives us the string which must mean that `filterText` which is of type `final JTextField` contains the information. Does that answer your question?

Comment: If I am following, the only place you are stating that the filter information is stored is only within the field in which it is entered? And that the filter information is not stored in the JTable object itself or the Sort object and can not be retrieved from there?

Comment: If you look at the code, you can find where everything is stored. The input is stored in the `filterText` which is a `JTextField` which you add to your `panel`. I am not quite sure what you mean by extracting it from the JTable, why do you want to extract it from that specifically?

Comment: Because the actual application is implemented differently and would require the ability to extract the information from the JTable if possible.

Comment: What you can do is to get all the contents from the `JPanel` with the method `getComponents()`. If you wonder how you can extract data from JTable I suggest you read the docs: [JTable Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html). And if the application is implemented so it is hard to retrieve data, why wouldnt you want to make it easier?

Comment: @UnhandledException, did any of the comments / answer help you resolve your problem?

Comment: No with regards to the original requirement. I have dropped this project and moved on to other endeavors.